# Java8: flatMap() Map<String, List<String>> to Map<String, Integer> where the Integer is the size of List<String> in initial map?

Tags: java

So if I have a map:

`Map<String, List<String>>` I want to end up with a map that holds the Key and the size of the list:

`Map<String, Integer>`?

Any good way to end up with this using the flatMap() of Java 8 streams?

Comment: Please, share your **attempt** and specify the problem you've encountered. Every question on StackOverflow is expected to demonstrate an effort. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 6):

I will start off by saying that [`Stream::flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) is definitely a weird option to choose. There are way better options, like just using a plain [`Stream::map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), or better yet, [`Collectors::toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-). In fact, I'd go so far as to say that using [`Stream::flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) would be a misuse of the library and probably something that would get red-flagged during a code review.

That said, if you must use a [`Stream::flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-), then here is how I would do it.

```java
   private void soq_20221217() // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74838895/java8-flatmap-mapstring-liststring-to-mapstring-integer-where-the-int
   {
   
      //https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-
      final Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
      
      map.put("abc", List.of("a", "b", "c"));
      map.put("defg", List.of("d", "e", "f", "g"));
      map.put("hijkl", List.of("h", "i", "j", "k", "l"));
      
      final 
         Map<String, Integer> 
         //var 
         counts = 
            map
               .entrySet()
               .stream()
               .flatMap(each -> Stream.of(Map.entry(each.getKey(), each.getValue().size())))
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))
               ;
         
      counts.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
   
   }
```

But like I said, the above is kind of undesirable. Here is a better way in my opinion. It's simpler too.

```java
   private void soq_20221217_better() // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74838895/java8-flatmap-mapstring-liststring-to-mapstring-integer-where-the-int
   {
   
      //https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-
      final Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
      
      map.put("abc", List.of("a", "b", "c"));
      map.put("defg", List.of("d", "e", "f", "g"));
      map.put("hijkl", List.of("h", "i", "j", "k", "l"));
      
      final 
         Map<String, Integer> 
         //var 
         counts = 
            map
               .entrySet()
               .stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, (each) -> each.getValue().size()))
               ;
         
      counts.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
   
   }
```

Ignoring the fact that it is one less line of code, it's also better because, unlike the first example, it follows the rules.

The entire point of [`Stream::flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) is that sometimes, you have a Stream of objects, where each of those objects is also capable of being stream'ed in some way. So, you call [`Stream::flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to map each object into a Stream, then merge each of those streams into your current one (also called flattening).

For example, you have a `Stream<String, List<String>>`. A `List<String>` can be stream'ed, so I can understand why you might think to do that.

However, your primary goal here is to go from `Map<String, List<String>>` to a `Map<String, Integer>`. Yes, you can stream the `List`, but what would that give you? How would streaming the `List<String>` help you get to your goal?

As I showed, there are some roundabout ways of using [`Stream::flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to get to your goal, but there is a perfectly useful [`List::size`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size--) function that can directly take you to your answer. Just use that function, and group your elements into a `Map<String, Integer>`. Job done.

Answer (score 1):

```java
Map<String, List<String>> map = ...;
Map<String, Integer> result = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().size()));
```